# Snowflake Virtual Warehouse usage consideration

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

When should you consider disabling auto-suspend for a Virtual Warehouse?
A. When users will be using compute at different times throughout a 24/7 period
B. When managing a steady workload
C. When the compute must be available with no delay or lag time
D. When you don’t want to have to manually turn on the Warehouse each time a user needs it

If we have to choose 2 options "B" is perfect but how about from "C" or "D" ?

Comment: This is one long run-on sentence without any punctuation that is vague and lacking detail. It also appears to be primarily opinion-based, because it lacks any meaningful information. You should read [ask], and then come back and [edit] it to be more specific and write it with punctuation so that it's readable.

Answer (score 3):

The most common reason to disable auto-suspend is in situations where you don't want to lose the cache that exists on the warehouse, which would add additional query time to the first few queries that are executed after a warehouse resumes.  In essence, when query time is critical and must be consistent, you'd potentially want to disable auto-suspend and allow the warehouse to stay up and running (either 24/7 or during a specified time period - using a task to suspend or resume the warehouse explicitly).

Comment: Hi Mike.. Thanks for explaining.. So from the below 4 points I can pick one which is Option "B" but what would be the best suitable 2nd option. Will it be "C" or "D"?
A. When users will be using compute at different times throughout a 24/7 period
B. When managing a steady workload
C. When the compute must be available with no delay or lag time
D. When you don’t want to have to manually turn on the Warehouse each time a user needs it

Comment: If those are the options, then C.  D isn't a correct answer because auto-resume and auto-suspend are 2 different things.  If a WH auto-suspends, it can auto-resume, which means you don't have to manually turn it on...ever.

If this is the answer you were looking for, please remember to mark the answer as the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks Mike...So what are the correct 2 options from the above 4 when the question is "When should you consider disabling auto-suspend for a Virtual Warehouse? choose 2